# C# Get Full URL Link of CSS background-image

Tags: c#, .net, url

I am parsing `CSS` file, and receive `background-image` property value in `CSS`, but the URL is not a full URL. It looks like this `url(../images/logo.png)`

How to get a full URL link for `background-image` property in `CSS` like http://www.aaa.aaa/aaa/aaa/aaa.png OR How to get an URL link for the image folder which contains that specific image?

Comment: Do you know the path of the CSS file?

Comment: Assume the path is not given and only website URL is given.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the absolute path by using [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28VS.90%29.aspx)

```
var absoluteUrl = this.Server.MapPath("../images/logo.png".Replace("..","~"));
```

This will result in `http://www.yoursite.com/images/logo.png`